# Verifying the switched supply design in AN920

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am following along with [AN920/D](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN920-D.PDF) *Theory and Applications of the MC34063 and uA78S40 Switching Regulator Control Circuits*, section *Step−Down Switching Regulator Design Example*.

[image: switched power supply diagram]

That is the diagram from the application note but I have changes. I am using the following parameters:

- Input (24V) and output (5V) same
- MC34063 instead of the μA78S40, connected the same way (Darlington configuration)
- \$f_{min}\$ basically the same at 50 kHz
- Maximum \$I_{out}\$ larger, at 150 mA
- \$V_{in(min)}\$ larger; for the supply of the previous stage I calculated this as

$$
V_{in(min)} = V_{in(nom)} \left( 1 - loadreg - tol \right)
$$
$$
24 \left( 1 - 5 \cdot 10^{-3}  - 1 \cdot 10^{-2} \right) = 23.64V
$$

- \$ V_{ripple-pp} \$ same at 25 mV
- Due to the different chip, a higher timing conductance of \$ 45 \mu S \$; and a slightly higher \$ V_{sattyp} = 875 mV \$
- Different external diode - Schottky, such as the SB140TA, with a much lower \$V_f\$ of at most 0.3 V, probably lower for these currents

For these parameters, I have calculated the following with a little Python:

```
 Rsc = 980.1 mΩ ~ 1.0 Ω
  R1 < 12.50 kΩ -> 3.4 kΩ
  R2 = 10 kΩ
  Co > 30.00 μF -> 470 μF
  Ct < 206.8 pF ~ 180 pF
   L > 272.1 μH -> 470 μH
 ton < 4.596 μs -> 4.000 μs
toff < 15.40 μs -> 13.41 μs
   f > 50.00 kHz -> 57.45 kHz
Vrip < 25.00 mV -> 1.389 mV
Vout = 5.000 V -> 5.000 V
```

I have tried to run the calculations backwards based on the approximated component values to verify:

- the frequency - above the minimum at 57kHz
- the output ripple voltage - below the maximum at 1.4mVpp
- the output voltage - exact, assuming centre values for components

Where I'm less certain is the effect of the much bigger L and the slightly bigger Rsc. In particular, for these calculations involving peak switch current:

[image: peak switch current]

Would it be meaningful to calculate a new peak current using the above equation based on my actual inductor value instead of the minimum value, and the actual time period instead of \$ t_{onmax} \$ ?  If so, would having a very large inductor harm the upper limit of the output current? Similarly, if I substitute the actual value of Rsc which is slightly higher, would that have the effect of a slightly lower maximum output current?

Also: the inductor I'm looking at has a DCR of 1.3Ω. How will this affect the circuit?

And does anything in this design look wrong?

Comment: You ought to specify min/max current and slew rate with ESR on cap then simulate it. L/DCR and ESR*C are important to phase margin at step load current overshoot and ripple.

Comment: What simulator can I use that supports the MC34063?

Comment: I guess you didn’t even bother to search